# How to do an accent insensitive string comparison in Golang?

Tags: string, go, accent-insensitive

I want to do case and accent insensitive string comparison in Go. I know how to perform case insensitive comparison (strings.EqualFold()). Not sure about accent insensitivity.

e.g. "Montreal" or "Montréal" should match with "montreal".

Any help is appreciated.